Is it possible to use ros2_control with Gazebo Harmonic and Humble
The question is in the title.
I think gz_ros2_control has to be build from source. But there are no vendor package for Humble. How can the be created?
Thanks
Michael

You can try to use the humble branch of gz_ros2_control, but acc. to the table here gazebo harmonic is not compatible with the ign_ros2_control (this was renamed after branching for iron).
